# Expo UIBackgroundModes audio is not working on iOS but works fine on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

Does anyone have the same issue and able to get around?

Here is [Expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#playing-or-recording-audio-in-background-ios) that explains how to enable audio to be played in the background as it shown below. However, it still does not play the audio in the background when phone goes to sleep.

```
"expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "audio"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems to be the issue from Expo but there's no activity on [Github issue page](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5472).

Comment: hello! are you doing this in the expo client? this feature only works in standalone apps

Comment: @brentvatne I ran `expo build:ios` to submit the app to app store. Standalone app means I have to eject the app?

Comment: in ios, watchdog kills the app after 30 sec after sleep mobile this is a policy of apple. you can play only the things which apple provide API like notification

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Thank you for the comment. What I'm trying to do is doing this enabling background mode for audio(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio) in Expo. I believe it's possible but just can't get it to work with Expo.

Comment: can you try this with TaskManager.defineTask https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/?redirected?

Comment: try this https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/6e8e454d6983e05c13469b2d8bf46550435e674d/docs/pages/versions/v34.0.0/sdk/task-manager.md#configuration-for-standalone-apps

Comment: That didn't work :( Thank you so much for the comment tho!